# Internet Explorer Session Expires Automatically when click img tag with VBA

Tags: vba, click

I have written a VBA code to scrap some web data. It logs in to a website. Click on a image which generates a table.

HTML:

```
<img onclick="submitfilter()" src="../../images/buttons/go.gif" style="CURSOR: hand" valign="center" align="top">
```

VBA to click:

```
html.getElementsByName("XXXXX")(0).getElementsByTagName("table")(1).Children(0).Children(0).Children(0).Children(0).Children(0).Children(3).getElementsByTagName("img")(1).Click
```

Now the problem is when the code runs at this point of the code the INTERNET EXPLORER says

**Your Session has been expired, Please Login again**

VBA script pops up this error

**Run-time Error '91':
Object Variable or With Block Variable not set.**

Please advise.

Kind regards,
Arif

Answer (score 0):

FYI.
Just found a solution.

When I am logged in and trying to navigate/jump to a different link of the same site I was entering

```
http://www.mysebsite.com/ / / /xxxxxxx.asp#
```

then the session would expire immediately.

But if I just remove www and navigate to

```
http://mysebsite.com/ / / /xxxxxxx.asp#
```

then it does not expire session and it works perfectly.